# Stored proc gives different result set than tsql, only on some servers

Tags: sql-server

This is a followup to a question I asked yesterday:

[Have you ever had SQL Server 2008 return a different result set than SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783115/have-you-ever-had-sql-server-2008-return-a-different-result-set-than-sql-server-2)

where I originally thought that the stored procedure was giving differnt results on sql2000 versus sql2008, but I have done quite a bit more narrowing down of the problem and eliminated quite a bit of code to get it down to a simple/reproducible problem. The summary is, an piece of TSQL when run as a proc returns a different answer that the same bit of code running as as just TSQL, **but only on my clients server**, not on either of my test servers.

When I run this TSQL:

```
DECLARE @PropertyID int 
DECLARE @PortfolioID    int 
DECLARE @StartDate  datetime 
DECLARE @EndDate    datetime 
DECLARE @AcctMethod tinyint 

SET @PropertyId=3555
--SET @PortfolioId = null
SET @StartDate= '3/1/2010'
SET @EndDate='2/28/2011'
SET @AcctMethod=1

DECLARE    @ErrorMsg    varchar(70)
DECLARE @ExclAcct tinyint

SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #IncomeStatement (
    PropertyID      int,
    GLAccountID     int,
    SubTotalAccountID   int,
    Debits          money,
    Credits         money,
    YTDDebits       money,
    YTDCredits      money,
    PZDebits        money,
    PZCredits       money,
    AccountType     tinyint
)

--Initialize Temporary Table
INSERT INTO #IncomeStatement(PropertyID, GLAccountID, SubTotalAccountID, AccountType, Debits, Credits, YTDDebits, YTDCredits, PZDebits, PZCredits)
SELECT PropertyID, ID, SubTotalAccountID, AccountType, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
FROM ChartOfAccounts
WHERE (PropertyID = @PropertyID OR @PropertyID Is Null)
    AND (@PortfolioID is null OR PropertyID in (select PropertyID from PortfolioProperty where PortfolioID=@PortfolioID))
    AND (Category > 3 or CashFlowCode <> 0)

--Period Activity
IF @AcctMethod = 1
    SET @ExclAcct = 0
ELSE
    SET @ExclAcct = 1

UPDATE Bal
SET 
    Debits = Debits +  D.TotDebit,
    Credits = Credits +  D.TotCredit
FROM #IncomeStatement Bal
    INNER JOIN (SELECT GLAccountID, Sum(Debit) AS TotDebit, Sum(Credit) AS TotCredit
            FROM GLTransaction GT
            WHERE (GT.PropertyID = @PropertyID OR @PropertyID Is Null)
                AND AccountingMethod <> @ExclAcct 
                AND Posted = 1
                AND TranDate >= @StartDate
                AND TranDate <= @EndDate
            GROUP BY GLAccountID) AS D
        ON BAL.GLAccountID = D.GLAccountID 

select * from #IncomeStatement  where GLAccountID=11153 
drop table    #IncomeStatement
```

I get a debit amount of $124.27, however, when I turn the above code into a stored procedure like this:

```
   CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_test]
    @PropertyID int = Null,
    @PortfolioID    int = Null,
    @StartDate  datetime = Null,
    @EndDate    datetime = Null,
    @AcctMethod tinyint = 1

AS


DECLARE    @ErrorMsg    varchar(70)
DECLARE @ExclAcct tinyint

SET NOCOUNT ON
CREATE TABLE #IncomeStatement (
    PropertyID      int,
    GLAccountID     int,
    SubTotalAccountID   int,
    Debits          money,
    Credits         money,
    YTDDebits       money,
    YTDCredits      money,
    PZDebits        money,
    PZCredits       money,
    AccountType     tinyint
)

--Initialize Temporary Table
INSERT INTO #IncomeStatement(PropertyID, GLAccountID, SubTotalAccountID, AccountType, Debits, Credits, YTDDebits, YTDCredits, PZDebits, PZCredits)
SELECT PropertyID, ID, SubTotalAccountID, AccountType, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
FROM ChartOfAccounts
WHERE (PropertyID = @PropertyID OR @PropertyID Is Null)
    AND (@PortfolioID is null OR PropertyID in (select PropertyID from PortfolioProperty where PortfolioID=@PortfolioID))
    AND (Category > 3 or CashFlowCode <> 0)

--Period Activity
IF @AcctMethod = 1
    SET @ExclAcct = 0
ELSE
    SET @ExclAcct = 1

UPDATE Bal
SET 
    Debits = Debits +  D.TotDebit,
    Credits = Credits +  D.TotCredit
FROM #IncomeStatement Bal
    INNER JOIN (SELECT GLAccountID, Sum(Debit) AS TotDebit, Sum(Credit) AS TotCredit
            FROM GLTransaction GT
            WHERE (GT.PropertyID = @PropertyID OR @PropertyID Is Null)
                AND AccountingMethod <> @ExclAcct 
                AND Posted = 1
                AND TranDate >= @StartDate
                AND TranDate <= @EndDate
            GROUP BY GLAccountID) AS D
        ON BAL.GLAccountID = D.GLAccountID 

select * from #IncomeStatement  where GLAccountID=11153 
drop table    #IncomeStatement
```

and then execute it loke this:

```
EXEC sp_test @PropertyID=3555, @StartDate='03/01/2010', @EndDate='02/28/2011'
```

I get a debit amount of $248.54, which is exactly double what it should be.

I am really stumped. The odder thing, is that if I backup this database, and then copy it to either my win2003 server running sql2000, or my win2008 server running SQL2008R2, it works correctly in both cases. So, it *seems* it is a server or database setting that is causing the problem, but have run out of things to check - hoping a fresh set of eyes can point out something obvious I am missing.

Comment: That's really odd. Can you tell if you're starting with the same number of records in #IncomeStatement in both cases? Also, have you tried using a table variable instead of a temp table? Maybe there's a setting on the tempdb on clients server that is causing some weirdness here.

Comment: Did you check if SET ANSI_NULLS makes a difference? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: ANSI_NULL setting has made no difference, and @rsbarro, yes the tables are the same - run in the same database one after the other with diff results.

Comment: @E.J. So if you put a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #IncomeStatement right before the --Period Activity comment in both the script and the stored procedure will you see the same # of records or more on the clients server vs your dev servers? I'm trying to rule out the UPDATE statement as part of the problem. Carrying that one step further, if the number of records are different, do you get the same result just running that first SELECT statement without adding the results to the #IncomeStatement temp table.

Comment: Not only is the count the same, the rows are all identical. I am running BOTH scripts on the same server, same database, one right after the other. I am starting to think it is a bug deep down in sql server that has been resolved in a SP. The server this happens on is SQL2000, SP3. On SP4 I can't duplicate it, nor on SQL2008

Comment: @E.J. OK, so you know it's working the same on both servers up to the --Period Activity comment at least. If you isolate the "SELECT GLAccountID, Sum(Debit) AS TotDebit..." statement and run that separately, is that also the same on both servers? If it is, then there must be something in the UPDATE Bal statement that is throwing it off, and I'd be really curious to see if the same behavior was seen if you switch #IncomeStatement to a table variable.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan please?

Comment: I posted a workaround below - I have spent *way* to much time tracking this down, the fix makes no sense, but maybe it gives a clue as to what went wrong in the first place.

Comment: @E.J. Very odd, sounds like a bad cached query plan. When you were testing, did you ever update the stored proc on the client server (I have to imagine you did)? Anyway, glad you figured it out.

Comment: Yes, I updated, recompiled, replaced proc multiple times - even created a new one with a different name; most frustrating bug I've tracked in a while

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, here is my fix - it absolutely doesn't not explain the original problem, but this is what I did:

Whenever I have a "parameter sniffing" performance issue, in order to solve that I declare 'local' variables for all parameters, assign those parameters to those variables, and then use only the local variables in the rest of the proc, like this:

```
  ALTER Procedure [dbo].[rptDateIncomeStatementPlusCash]
        @PropertyID int = Null,
        @PortfolioID    int = Null,
        @StartDate  datetime = Null,
        @EndDate    datetime = Null,
        @AcctMethod tinyint = 1
    AS
      DECLARE   @xPropertyID    int 
      DECLARE   @xPortfolioID   int 
      DECLARE   @xStartDate datetime 
      DECLARE   @xEndDate   datetime 
      DECLARE   @xAcctMethod    tinyint 

      SET @xPropertyID= @PropertyId
      SET @xPortfolioId = @PortfolioId
      SET @xStartDate = @StartDate
      SET @xEndDate = @EndDate
      SET @xAcctMethod = @AcctMethod
```

the similarity is that when parameter sniffing is an issue, you can run a stored proc thru MGMT studio and get better performance than running it as an SQL, and changes (like those above), usually fix it.

In my case I was seeing a difference between straight TSQL versus executing the proc(although it was not performance related), I gave it a try - and presto it worked; I wish I had a better explanation, because quite honestly I find it scary to think that SQL server will on occassion give inconsistent results when running nearly identical code.

I did find [this bulletin from MS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976603) about a similar but different problem, that at least does confirm that under the right circumstances, SQL server may give you bad answers, and [this related bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/386810/concurrent-use-of-option-recompile-causes-incorrect-results) with this key phrase:

> Description: Two sessions each make
>   many calls to a procedure P with
>   changing parameter values. The
>   procedure P executes one query against
>   static data, sometimes with OPTION
>   (RECOMPILE) and sometimes without.
>
> Occasionally P gives incorrect results
>   (for the repro below, this typically
>   happens about 1/2% - 1% of the time).
>   **When P's results are wrong, P returns
>   either 0 or twice the expected number
>   of rows.**

*Someone yesterday left a comment about parameter sniffing as a possibility but for whatever reason they deleted their comments (or answer) so I can't give credit to them for the tip.*

Comment: We have a procedure that generates possible matches for a lotto algorithm used by a firm in a country where they are required to have a mathematical return of, say, 50% back to all of the customers for lottery games. An issue we had with the query was that if we ran the stored proc directly it wouldn't return any results below 80%, but if we highlighted the block in SSMS and ran it, we would get a much better distribution of values. We weren't changing parameter values, but doing what was in here - creating new vars and assigning the values - worked flawlessly. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

[image: Here is the execution plan, for those interested - could figure out how do this as a comment]

Comment: This is in response to the comment above looking for the execution plan - couldn't add it as a comment.

Comment: Wonder if you hit a bug with paralellism - With 2 concurrent threads both processing the same data or something. Looks like there were [a few paralellism bugs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888799) fixed in SQL Server 2000 SP4 but I couldn't see one that looked clearly related.