# Stored proc gives different result set on different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have put together a stored procedure on my dev machine, which runs SQL Server 10.50.6220 (Express). It works correctly and returns the expected (and consistent) results.

I have then done a full backup and restored to a test machine running SQL Server 10.50.6000.34. The stored proc on the new server now returns incorrect results, whats more, the results it returns are different each time it is run.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Station_Utilisation]
@From       NVARCHAR(50),
@To         NVARCHAR(50)

AS

IF @From='' SET @From = NULL
IF @To='' SET @To = NULL

SELECT T.StationID As [Station ID], dbo.Stations.StationName As [Station Name], T.StaffWorking As [Workers], T.Mins
FROM
    (SELECT StatsID As StationID, [Count] As StaffWorking, SUM(Duration) AS Mins
    FROM
        (SELECT dbo.Active_Clockings.StationID AS StatsID, COUNT(*) AS [Count], DATEDIFF(Minute, Times2.Time, Times1.Time) AS Duration
        FROM            
            (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rownum, [Time]
            FROM            
                (SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.StartTime) AS [Time]
                FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings
                UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime) AS [Time]
                FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings) AS AllTimes
                ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS Times1 JOIN
                    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) AS rownum, [Time]
                    FROM
                        (SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.StartTime) AS [Time]
                        FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings
                        UNION
                        SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime) AS [Time]
                        FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings) AS AllTimes
                        ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS Times2 ON Times1.rownum = Times2.rownum + 1 JOIN
                            dbo.Active_Clockings ON Times1.Time > dbo.Active_Clockings.StartTime AND Times2.Time < dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime
                            AND (@From IS NULL OR (dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime > CAST(@From as date)))
                            AND (@To IS NULL OR dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime < DATEADD(Day, 1, CAST(@To as date)))
                        GROUP BY Times1.rownum, Times2.Time, Times1.Time, dbo.Active_Clockings.StationID) AS Totals
                GROUP BY [Count], StatsID
) AS T INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Stations ON T.StationID= dbo.Stations.ID
ORDER BY T.StationID, T.StaffWorking ASC
```

Each row of underlying data contains a staff member, the station they were working at and their start & finish times. The purpose of the stored proc is to return a list of stations, along with the number of mins that each quantity of workers were at that station, as below:

[image]

My question is, what could be causing the incorrect and inconsistent results on the test server? And what can I do to fix it?

I have read this, possibly related, question:

[Stored proc gives different result set than tsql, only on some servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795789/stored-proc-gives-different-result-set-than-tsql-only-on-some-servers)

and have tried creating local variables for the parameters but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess it's a language issue. You're declaring your parameters as a `nvarchar`, however, they're being compared to `time` and `date` datatypes. Your parameters should be the same data type as the columns they will be used against. Also, when passing a value to (from SQL) to that parameter, you should be using a non-ambigous format. For `date` that would be `yyyyMMdd` (i.e. `'20180618'`) and for `datetime` it would be `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sss` (I.e. `'2018-06-18T12:43:17.753'`).

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your suggestion. However, I don't think that is the issue as the problem still occurs if I pass NULL to both From and To. The reason I am passing them as NVARCHAR is because they are being accessed by excel and I had a huge problem trying to pass datetime values. This was the only way I got it to work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what could be causing the inconsistent results

1. Non-deterministic ordering

   ```
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT 1))
   ```

   By `ORDER BY(SELECT 1)` you are telling the optimiser here that you don't care in which order the rows will be numbered. I didn't analyse the whole query, but is it really the case?
2. Another bit that has a strong smell is `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT` with some `ORDER BY` in the inner/subquery. It looks like you think that adding `ORDER BY` like this in the inner query guarantees something. It doesn't.

---

If you need your row numbers ordered by `[Time] DESC`, then put it in `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time] DESC)
```

Comment: Nice spots. I hadn't noticed the `(ORDER BY(SELECT 1))`.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at your suggestions. To be honest, a lot of the code has been scavenged from here there and everywhere, then I have amended and added to it. So it is highly likely not the best way of achieving what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Vladimir, I have managed to tweak the stored procedure so that it returns the correct results. As suggested, I moved the sorting behavior to the ROW_NUMBER function, rather than the ORDER BY clause (although it actually needed to be ASC, not DESC).

I will mark his answer as correct but thought I would post my final code here for completeness:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_Station_Utilisation]
@From       NVARCHAR(50),
@To         NVARCHAR(50)

AS

IF @From='' SET @From = NULL
IF @To='' SET @To = NULL


SELECT T.StationID As [Station ID], dbo.Stations.StationName As [Station Name], T.StaffWorking As [Workers], T.Mins
FROM
    (SELECT StatsID As StationID, [Count] As StaffWorking, SUM(Duration) AS Mins
    FROM
        (SELECT dbo.Active_Clockings.StationID AS StatsID, COUNT(*) AS [Count], DATEDIFF(Minute, Times2.Time, Times1.Time) AS Duration
        FROM            
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time] ASC) AS rownum, [Time]
            FROM            
                (SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.StartTime) AS [Time]
                FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings
                UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime) AS [Time]
                FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings) AS AllTimes
                ) AS Times1 JOIN
                    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time] ASC) AS rownum, [Time]
                    FROM
                        (SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.StartTime) AS [Time]
                        FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings
                        UNION
                        SELECT DISTINCT (dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime) AS [Time]
                        FROM    dbo.Active_Clockings) AS AllTimes
                        ) AS Times2 ON Times1.rownum = Times2.rownum + 1 JOIN
                            dbo.Active_Clockings ON Times1.Time > dbo.Active_Clockings.StartTime AND Times2.Time < dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime
                            AND (@From IS NULL OR (dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime > CAST(@From as date)))
                            AND (@To IS NULL OR dbo.Active_Clockings.FinishTime < DATEADD(Day, 1, CAST(@To as date)))
                        GROUP BY Times1.rownum, Times2.Time, Times1.Time, dbo.Active_Clockings.StationID) AS Totals
                GROUP BY [Count], StatsID
) AS T INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Stations ON T.StationID= dbo.Stations.ID
ORDER BY T.StationID, T.StaffWorking ASC
```