# Results returned from Sql Server changes according to the login I'm using

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a view to identify the shift adjustments of our employee database.

Here when I login with the admin login and run the query i get 27 records. when i login with a read-only login and run the query i only get 1 record.

any suggestion why this is happening?

this is my query

```
SELECT dbo.DailyAttendance.EmployeeCode AS EMP_NUMBER,
       dbo.ShiftAdjustment.Date AS RSD_DATE,
       dbo.ShiftDefinition.ShiftName AS SFT_CODE,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), dbo.ShiftDetail.InTime, 108) AS SFT_TIMEIN,
       CONVERT(varchar(5), dbo.ShiftDetail.OutTime, 108) AS SFT_TIMEOUT,
       dbo.DailyAttendance.Date AS IOT_INDATE,
       CONVERT(varchar(5), dbo.DailyAttendance.InTime, 108) AS IOT_INTIME,
       dbo.DailyAttendance.OutDate AS IOT_OUTDATE, CONVERT(varchar(5),
       dbo.DailyAttendance.OutTime, 108) 
AS IOT_OUTTIME, dbo.ShiftDetail.LeaveDays AS SFT_LEAVEAMOUNT,
CASE WHEN dbo.ShiftDetail.Midnight = 'False' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS SFT_MIDNIGHT

FROM dbo.DailyAttendance INNER JOIN
 dbo.ShiftAdjustment ON dbo.DailyAttendance.EmployeeCode =
 dbo.ShiftAdjustment.EmployeeCode AND
 dbo.DailyAttendance.Date = dbo.ShiftAdjustment.Date AND
 YEAR(dbo.ShiftAdjustment.Date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND
 DATEPART(wk, dbo.ShiftAdjustment.Date) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) +
 CASE WHEN datepart(dw, getdate()) <= 2 THEN - 1 ELSE 0 END
 INNER JOIN dbo.Shift WITH (nolock) ON
 dbo.ShiftAdjustment.ShiftCode = dbo.ShiftDefinition.ShiftCode
 INNER JOIN dbo.ShiftDetail ON
 dbo.DailyAttendance.DayType = dbo.ShiftDetail.DayType AND
 dbo.ShiftAdjustment.ShiftCode = dbo.ShiftDetail.ShiftCode

 WHERE (dbo.ShiftAdjustment.EmployeeCode IS NOT NULL) AND
 (YEAR(dbo.DailyAttendance.Date) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND
 (DATEPART(wk, dbo.DailyAttendance.Date) = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()) + 
 CASE WHEN datepart(dw, getdate()) <= 2 THEN - 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783115/have-you-ever-had-sql-server-2008-return-a-different-result-set-than-sql-server

Comment: found it,

it all depends on this line, select datepart(dw,getdate())

for the admin log in it returns 2 and for my read-only log in it returns 3. that's the reason for the difference in the results set.

in SQL server the starting date of the week is Sunday (default value).
Someone has changed it for the admin login. :(

Comment: Yes, that could do it. Try to write code that uses date functions so that it doesn't *matter* what `SET DATEFIRST` setting is in effect.

Comment: yes everything in the from clause are tables. the collation is the same although the default schema is different.

Comment: I'm trying (and failing) to get a good grasp on what you're trying to do with all of that date related code. If you could write a clear spec for what it's meant to do, I could try to re-write it so that it'll work no matter what user settings are in effect - if you're still looking for help.

Comment: hi sorry for the delay in replying, i figured it out. the issue was with my logins default language. Im keeping it as English and then this returns me expected results. :)